# ASP.NET Core uploads files using IFormFile with a path in the file name

Tags: asp.net-core

```
 [HttpPost("FilePost")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FilePost(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        long size  = files.Sum(f => f.Length);
        var filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/files";
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        }

        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            if (item.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath,FileMode.CreateNew))
                {
                    await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }
        return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath });

    }
```

FormFile. FileName = directory + filename,

Uploaded file, file name with path information, how to do?

I just need to get the name of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just need to get the name of the file.

Use `Path.GetFileName()` to get the name of the file , and use `Path.Combine()` to combine the the save path you want with the file name , try the code like below

```
 var filesPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/files";
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(filesPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(filesPath);
        }

        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            if (item.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(item.FileName);
                var filePath = Path.Combine(filesPath, fileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filesPath, FileMode.CreateNew))
                {
                    await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am glad to help you , could you mark my reply as an answer ?It will help others who have the same doubts to find the answer quickly . If you don't know how to mark the answer , pleaser refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) . Thanks a lot !

Comment: There's a minor correction: you should construct the FileStream with filePath instead of filesPath

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you want to get the file name base on your file path.
You can get it into way

```
using System.IO;

Path.GetFileName(filePath);
```

or extension method

```
public static string GetFilename(this IFormFile file)
{
    return ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(
                    file.ContentDisposition).FileName.ToString().Trim('"');
}
```

Please let me know if you need any help

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with different browsers. IE send FileName with full path and Chrome send only the file name. I used `Path.GetFileName()` to overcome issue.

Other fix is at your front end side. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http) this to solve from it front end side.